# How to create a Sales Order with manual numbering sequence in microsoft dynamics ax2012

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012

I have configured sales order numbering sequence as Manual in AR Parameters screen, but while creating a sales order by selecting Customer Account->click on OK. I am getting the following message "field sales order must be filled in" and i am trying to create a manual number to the sales order. Please suggest anyone to proceed.

Thanks,
Meghasyam

Comment: Have you created any number sequence? Can you show the screens or code to us?

Answer (score 1):

If sales order number sequence configured as **Manual** it means that *SalesId* value will not be generated by the system and should be entered by the user. 
The field *SalesId* is setted as mandatory on `SalesTable` and must be populated before sales order record could be saved. That why you got this error:

> Field 'Sales order' must be filled in.